# Micrsoft Threat Modeling Tool 2016 make a bi-directional connect

Tags: threat-modeling, sdl

How do you make to two processes Bi-directional? I see that sometimes when I right click on the MS threat modeling tool that there is a bidirectional option but it is greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

Select the two processes and right click Bi-directional. 
[image: Two application make a bi-directional connect]